# How can I reapply for my refused B1/B2 Visa (Denial under 214B)?

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, visa-rejections

Got my B1/B2 visa refused 20 days ago under 214-B. He just asked normal questions like why, with whom, for how many days, how much experience I have and how much I earn... and refused it.

I have 1.8 yrs experience and have a package of 240000 INR per year. I needed to re-apply asap.

What should be the best route I take to get it approved? When can be the best time? Will the bond of 3 yrs work? or what type of strong evidences I can show?

Comment: What exactly is 2.4l?  The issue is, again, whether or not you will go back after your visit.  So it will all depend on your circumstances.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a salary of 2.4 lakh/year (India), but I could be radically wrong.

Comment: Difficult to answer this unless you provide more information; like what was the purpose of your trip, what was the documentation provided by you?

Comment: You are correct @ZachLipton, that is what that number is. Basically 240,000 INR per Year or about USD 300/month at the current exchange rate.

Comment: Can you also share what the reason for this urgency is (I mean by needing to re-apply asap) Do you have family in the US, can they sponsor your application? Do you plan to pursue further education there? Are you married, do you have kids, how old you are etc...

Comment: Were you planning to pay for your trip yourself?  You can spend $300 *a day* to visit most big cities.  If you didn't show a credible source of outside funding, they might have taken this as evidence of disqualification or of immigrant intent (that you would try to work to support yourself).

Comment: Hi all, thanks.. Am 24-single and works as a Project Analyst in India. No relatives and no travel history. My company wants me to be there to analyze the business process of our client (am working on that project since the start-1 year as an integral part). We need to deliver a comprehensive IT solution to them which is the reason they want my visa to get approved asap. I have the sponsorship and invitation letter with me (though i also had them before, but they didn't asked for any doc)

Comment: @Cheena 24 years old, single, no family, with monthly income barely sufficient for 2-3 weeks...  You're a walking RED FLAG.

Comment: @Karlson And skills that pay 15x as much in the USA if he can produce some sort of document. I think that's rather a low salary for the job even in India; I wonder if that also came into play.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus It might have, but I think that no family of any sort played a bigger role.  Given that it's on business the sponsorship may take care of the financial angle.